# Comparing all variables in PCR function from pls package, R

Tags: r, regression, pca, multivariate-testing, pls

I am trying to conduct a Principal Components Regression Analysis (PCR) in R. Usually I would do a PCA (Principal Components Analysis), however I have multi-collinearity and have read that PCR can handle this.

I am using the `pcr`function from the `pls` package. This requires a formula to identify the variables to be compared. I want to be able to compare every variable against every other variable, the way a PCA does. However in this function I can only figure out how to compare one variable against every other variable, and depending on which variable I choose, the result changes. Of course, it is possible I am not understanding PCR correctly.

Here is an example using the `iris` data set.

```
library(pls)
library(ggplot2)
```

Comparing `Petal.Length` to all other variables:

```
ir.pcr<-pcr(Petal.Length~ ., data = iris, validation = "CV")#PCR comparing `Petal.Length` with all other variables

df<-data.frame(ir.pcr$scores[,1],ir.pcr$scores[,2])#get first 2 COMP scores from PCR for ggplot
colnames(df)<-c('Comp1', 'Comp2')
   
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Comp1,y=Comp2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=iris$Species),shape=21,colour='black',size=3)#plot points
```

[image]

Using `Sepal.Width` compared to every other variable:

```
ir.pcr<-pcr(Sepal.Width~ ., data = iris, validation = "CV")#PCR

df<-data.frame(ir.pcr$scores[,1],ir.pcr$scores[,2])#get first 2 COMP scores from PCR for ggplot
colnames(df)<-c('Comp1', 'Comp2')

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Comp1,y=Comp2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=iris$Species),shape=21,colour='black',size=3)#plot points
```

[image]

My understanding is that including a `.` after `~` in a formula means 'compare to everything else'. If this is so, then how can I essentially have `.~.` to be able to compare every variable to every other variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCR is principal components **regression**. That means that you have one dependent variable (on a left hand side of `~`) and many independent variables (right hand side of `~`) just like in linear regression.

PCR first conducts **PCA on independent variables** only, and then regresses dependent variable on principal components from PCA. That is why you get different results when chosing different dependent variables.

This helps dealing with **multicollinearity of independent variables** only. So this technique is useful when you'd like to run linear regression but you have multicollinearity issue with independent variables. It is not useful in dimension reduction task (e.g. when you don't have specified dependent variable), as PCA is.

Comment: This is grave news indeed! Can you explain why PCR is not useful for dimension reduction with multicollinearity? Can you suggest an analysis that is? Thank you for this in depth answer.

Comment: Beacuse it does not reduce dimension of whole dataset. It reduces dimension of independent variables only and you do not have distinction between dependent and independent variables.

Comment: Forget about multicollinearity for a while. Would you use linear regression for your problem? Probably not, because it assesses relationship between one dependent variable andmany independent variable. This is not what you need. Now, bring multicollinearity again. PCR is a way to do linear-regression-like analysis with multicollinearity present. But you are not interested in linear regression, so you don't need linear-regression-like technique.